# I need help getting this program to properly print my outputs

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>              /*printf and scanf option*/
#include <math.h>

void change(double coin_change, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies);          /*function protype*/

int main(void)
{
    int fifties = 0, twenties = 0, tens = 0, fives = 0, dollars = 0, quarters = 0, dimes = 0, nickels = 0, pennies = 0;
    double amt_paid = 0, amt_due = 0, amt_change = 0, coin_change = 0;          /*declared avriables*/

    printf("Enter the amount paid> ");                  /*Prompt user to enter amount paid*/
    scanf("%lf", &amt_paid);

    printf("Enter the amount due> ");                   /*Prompt user to enter amount due*/
    scanf("%lf", &amt_due);

    amt_change = amt_paid - amt_due;                    /*Formula for amount of change to be given*/
    dollars = (amt_change);

    coin_change = (int)((amt_change - (amt_change)) * 100 + 0.5);
    coin_change = coin_change * 100;
    printf("\n%f\n", coin_change);

    change(coin_change, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies);

    printf("Change is fifties: %d$, twenties: %d$, tens: %d$, fives: %d$, dollars: %d$, quarters: %d, dimes: %d, nickels: %d,\
           pennies: %d", fifties, twenties, tens, fives, dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);  
    return(0);
}

void change(double coin_change, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies)
{
    int q = 1, d = 1, n = 1, p = 1;
    do {
        if(coin_change >= 25){
            *quarters = *quarters + q;
            coin_change = coin_change - 25;
        }
        else if (coin_change >= 10) {
            *dimes = *dimes + d;
            coin_change = coin_change - 10;
        }
        else if (coin_change  >=  5) {
            *nickels = *nickels + n;
            coin_change = coin_change - 5;
        }
        else if (coin_change >= 1) {
            *pennies = *pennies + p;
            coin_change = coin_change - 1;
        }
    } while (coin_change >= 1);
}
```

I'm sorry I wasn't very clear the first time. What I need is to create what is basically a cash register program. When given the amount due, and the amount paid from the user, i should receive output that tell me how many 50 dollar bills, 20s, 10s, 5s, 1s, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies I should be receiving as change. As I am new to programming, the code you see is what is to the best of my knowledge. I do need to improve or even completely change it. What I am really looking to do is pinpoint my mistakes, and fix them. I am hoping to have this code done soon. I feel that I am close, but only just missing it. Maybe I am wrong, but that is what I am coming to you guys for.

Comment: Please simplify your program to the simplest thing that demonstrates the error, then give us the input, the expected output, and the actual output.  Also read http://sscce.org

Comment: What's so bad about printing "the right amount of dollars"?  Sounds good.

Comment: Every time you format code like this, God kills a kitten.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: What's this thing for? `(int)((amt_change - (amt_change)) * 100 + 0.5)`

Comment: For starters, remove the unused variables (_e.g._ `fifties`) and initialize all of the others.  The approach of subtracting as many quarters, then dimes, _etc._, in order of decreasing value, is a good one, but you don't need `q`, `d`, `n`, or `p` because you only need to increment your counters.  Apply the same technique to calculate the bills: first subtract fifties, then twenties, _etc_.

Comment: @sarnold: It looks like an attempt to calculate the integer-dollar portion of the change, but the calculation is incorrect.

Comment: @AdamLiss I need to use the fifties varaiable, not get rid of it, but I am so new to this stuff it is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. you have many unused variables: `fifties`, `twenties`, `tens`, `fives`, `dollars`, etc.
2. The lines here:

   `coin_change = (int)((amt_change - (amt_change)) * 100 + 0.5);`
   `coin_change = coin_change * 100;`

   Are wrong. They should be replaced with something like the following:

   `coin_change = (100 * amt_change)`.
3. Have you heard of the `+=` / `-=` operators? They'd turn these lines:

   `*quarters = *quarters + q;`
   `coin_change = coin_change - 25;`

   Into this:

   `*quarters += q;`
   `coin_change -= 25;`

After I fixed those things, your code worked fine.

Comment: `coin_change` is the amount of change less than a dollar.  Your formula calculates the _entire_ amount of change in cents.  Does the code that "worked fine" work when the change is more than $50? Also, have you heard of the `++` operator?  `++*quarters`

Comment: @AdamLiss the formula that he supplied does not take amounts over a quarter into account, and his code uses a variable `q`, so I kept it as it was.

Comment: Well i am definitely doing this wrong. So what I need is to make a code that will give me change even if it is over $50, using 50s, 20s, 10, etc

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII How do I use those unused variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write the code for you because this smells like homework, but here's the algorithm:

```
read_from_keyboard(amount_due)
read_from_keyboard(amount_paid)
change = amount_paid - amount_due

for each denomination in (
  fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies) {

  while (change >= value of denomination) {
     increment counter for denomination
     subtract value of denomination from change
  }

  print counter + name of denomination  // Ex: "4 twenties"
}
```

The "trick" is to realize that you can treat whole dollar values and coins in exactly the same way -- part of the art of programming is being able to find a generic solution that you can re-use, rather than handling each situation as a special case.

You may want to convert the change to an integer that represents the value in cents, so you can avoid the rounding errors that floating-point arithmetic creates.

Good luck!